# How can I change date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using this query

```
SELECT 
    A.EMP_NO, A.EMP_NAME, A.DEPARTMENT_NAME, A.ATT_DATE, 
    CASE 
       WHEN B.EMP_NO IS NULL 
          THEN 'A' 
          ELSE 'P' 
    END PRESENT_STATUS  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         A.EMP_NO, A.EMP_NAME, A.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
         B.ATT_DATE  
     FROM 
         EMPLOYEES A, 
         (SELECT 
              TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE) + LEVEL ATT_DATE  
          FROM DUAL  
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_DATE(:P_TO_DATE) - TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE)) B
    WHERE 
        TRIM(TO_CHAR(B.ATT_DATE, 'DAY')) <> 'SUNDAY') A,  
        (SELECT EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME, TRUNC(TIME_STAMP) ATT_DATE  
      FROM EMP22  
      GROUP BY EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME, TRUNC(TIME_STAMP)) B  
WHERE A.EMP_NO = B.EMP_NO(+) AND A.ATT_DATE = B.ATT_DATE(+)  
GROUP BY A.EMP_NO, A.EMP_NAME, A.DEPARTMENT_NAME, A.ATT_DATE, B.EMP_NO
```

query result   is like this

```
| EMP_Name | emp_NO | Department_name | 2013-06-01 | 2013-06-02 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-04 | 2013-06-05 | 
|  Naren   |      1 |         22 |         A |        A |            A |           A |          P |           
|  Srinu   |      2 |         22 |         P |        P |            P |           P |          P |        
|  Blah    |      3 |         22 |         A |        P |            P |           P |          P |
```

I need result like this date should be like this

```
| EMP_Name | emp_NO | Department_name | 01 | 02 | 03 |04 | 05 | 
|  Naren |          1 |                        22 |                A |   A |   A |  A |   P |           
|  Srinu |            2 |                       22 |                P |   P |    P |  P |   P |        
|  Blah |             3 |                       22 |                 A |   P |   P |   P |   P |
```

can you please help me modify my query

Comment: That query doesn't produce that output. Is this only part of what you are running?

Comment: As Alex says, that output doesn't match that query. I'd also note that column names can be aliased to whatever you want without changing query logic.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: query is correct and i am getting my result just need to show Date like this 05 06 in place of 05-MAY-2016

Comment: You seem to be pivoting the result of the query you've shown, but unless you're hard-coding them you wouldn't get those column headers within a plain Oracle query. So are you passing this through a dynamic PL/SQL pivot function? Or pivoting in an external tool like Excel? Either way you've left out an important (maybe the most important) part of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    A.EMP_NO, A.EMP_NAME, A.DEPARTMENT_NAME, to_char(A.ATT_DATE, 'dd'), 
    CASE 
       WHEN B.EMP_NO IS NULL 
          THEN 'A' 
          ELSE 'P' 
    END PRESENT_STATUS  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         A.EMP_NO, A.EMP_NAME, A.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
         B.ATT_DATE  
     FROM 
         EMPLOYEES A, 
         (SELECT 
              TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE) + LEVEL ATT_DATE  
          FROM DUAL  
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_DATE(:P_TO_DATE) - TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE)) B
    WHERE 
        TRIM(TO_CHAR(B.ATT_DATE, 'DAY')) <> 'SUNDAY') A,  
        (SELECT EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME, TRUNC(TIME_STAMP) ATT_DATE  
      FROM EMP22  
      GROUP BY EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, DEPARTMENT_NAME, TRUNC(TIME_STAMP)) B  
WHERE A.EMP_NO = B.EMP_NO(+) AND A.ATT_DATE = B.ATT_DATE(+)  
GROUP BY A.EMP_NO, A.EMP_NAME, A.DEPARTMENT_NAME, A.ATT_DATE, B.EMP_NO
```